# Weight painter - no weight paint but section affected by an unconnected bone

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I'm new to Blender and I have weird behavior I think. My model's arm is somehow affecting its hip but no weight at the hip!
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PAD6KoP8" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PAD6KoP8/). Thanks!

Comment: the whole underside of the arm doesn't have weightpaint either, and as Galileo said: "yet it moves”

Comment: It has weight, i think because i selected multiple bones in the screenshot to see if multiple bones could show unintended weight somewhere.

Comment: oops, my bad. moonbots answered this well, but if you select the Lower Arm.L vertex group in edit mode you'll see that a big chunk of the body is part of it and removing it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new as well... did you apply automatic weights? The automatic weights seems to be hit or miss with me, and I have to go in and manually change it.

Comment: No automatic weights.

Answer (score 0):

If you activate the *Zero Weight* option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel, you can see that this part of your mesh is still blue, and not black, it means that this bone has a small influence on it:

[image]

You can substract this influence in *Weight Paint* mode, just make sure that the *Front Faces Only* and the *Front-face Falloff* options are activated to be able to paint through:

[image]

You can also select this vertex in *Edit* mode and in the N panel check what vertex group it is part of, and remove it from this vertex group:

[image]

Comment: Wow I would not have known to do all of that. Thanks so much!